# Using VBA to get first image link from Google

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the below code to get the first image link from Google for certain values I'm searching for. 
but it's giving me Google's logo image.

[Screenshot for the results I'm currently getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhlGg.png)

Can you please help me modify it to get the accurate image? 
Plus I need to modify it to get large images. 
Can you please support on that?

```
Public Sub Test()
Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLdoc As HTMLDocument
Dim imgElements As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim imgElement As HTMLImg
Dim aElement As HTMLAnchorElement
Dim N As Integer, I As Integer
Dim Url As String, Url2 As String
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim m, sImageSearchString

LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For I = 1 To LastRow
    Url = "http://www.google.co.in/search?q=" & Cells(I, 1) & "&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&rnd=1"
    Set IE = New InternetExplorer

    With IE
        .Visible = False
        .Navigate Url 'sWebSiteURL

        Do Until .readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
            'Do Until IE.document.readyState = "Complete": DoEvents: Loop

            Set HTMLdoc = .document

            Set imgElements = HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("IMG")

            N = 1
            For Each imgElement In imgElements
                If InStr(imgElement.src, sImageSearchString) Then
                    If imgElement.ParentNode.nodeName = "A" Then
                        Set aElement = imgElement.ParentNode

                        Url2 = imgElement.src
                        N = N + 1
                    End If
                End If
            Next

            Cells(I, 2) = Url2

            IE.Quit
            Set IE = Nothing
        End With
    Next End Sub
```

Comment: If you just want the first image on the page, just `Exit For` once you have set the value for `Url2`. You don't need to keep looping if you have already got the image

Comment: Hello @Zac can you please explain more?

Comment: Exactly what @jsotola did

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Public Sub Test()

    Dim I As Integer
    Dim Url As String
    Dim m, sImageSearchString

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim HTMLdoc As HTMLDocument
    Dim allImgElements As IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim imgElement As HTMLDivElement

    Dim IE As InternetExplorer         ' open IE before start of loop
    Set IE = New InternetExplorer
    IE.Visible = False

    For I = 1 To LastRow

        Url = "http://www.google.co.in/search?q=" & Cells(I, 1) & "&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&rnd=1"

        IE.Navigate Url                                    ' sWebSiteURL

        Do Until IE.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
        'Do Until IE.document.readyState = "Complete": DoEvents: Loop

        Set HTMLdoc = IE.document

        Set allImgElements = HTMLdoc.getElementsByClassName("rg_bx rg_di rg_el ivg-i")

        For Each imgElement In allImgElements
            If imgElement.getAttribute("data-ri") = "0" Then    ' pictures are numbered
                Debug.Print "found"
                Exit For
            End If
        Next imgElement

        Cells(I, 2) = imgElement.ChildNodes.Item(0).href

    Next I

    IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing

End Sub

' this is html for one image from google

'      look for these     -------------------------+----------------+
'                                                  V                V
'    <div jscontroller="Q7Rsec" data-lpd="650" data-ri="0" class="rg_bx rg_di rg_el ivg-i" data-ved="0ahUKEwivgb2k5unVAhUKiFQKHSiFBlMQMwg6KAAwAA" data-row="0" style="width: 271px; height: 162px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; display: inline-block;">
'        <a jsname="hSRGPd" href="/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fi.ytimg.com%2Fvi%2FSfLV8hD7zX4%2Fmaxresdefault.jpg&amp;imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DSfLV8hD7zX4&amp;docid=JkkgT0Wh9FO29M&amp;tbnid=_vUAT67U1HGFHM%3A&amp;vet=10ahUKEwivgb2k5unVAhUKiFQKHSiFBlMQMwg6KAAwAA..i&amp;w=1280&amp;h=720&amp;bih=675&amp;biw=1366&amp;q=dog&amp;ved=0ahUKEwivgb2k5unVAhUKiFQKHSiFBlMQMwg6KAAwAA&amp;iact=mrc&amp;uact=8" jsaction="fire.ivg_o;mouseover:str.hmov;mouseout:str.hmou" class="rg_l" rel="noopener" style="background: rgb(216, 190, 146); width: 271px; height: 162px; left: 0px;">
'            <img class="rg_ic rg_i" data-sz="f" name="_vUAT67U1HGFHM:" jsaction="load:str.tbn" alt="Image result for dog" onload="google&amp;&amp;google.aft&amp;&amp;google.aft(this)" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4Aa+Zd0Fh ...............  PRHHA47Hs//2Q==" style="width: 289px; height: 162px; margin-left: -5px; margin-right: -13px; margin-top: 0px;">
'            <div class="_aOd rg_ilm">
'                <div class="rg_ilmbg">
'                    <span class="rg_ilmn"> 1280&nbsp;×&nbsp;720 - youtube.com </span>
'                </div>
'            </div>
'        </a>
'    <div jsname="ik8THc" class="rg_meta notranslate">{"cl":3,"cr":9,"id":"_vUAT67U1HGFHM:","isu":"youtube.com","itg":0,"ity":"jpg","oh":720,"ou":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/SfLV8hD7zX4/maxresdefault.jpg","ow":1280,"pt":"Jealous Dog Want Attention Compilation NEW - YouTube","rid":"JkkgT0Wh9FO29M","rmt":0,"rt":0,"ru":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v\u003dSfLV8hD7zX4","s":"Jealous Dog Want Attention Compilation NEW","st":"YouTube","th":168,"tu":"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q\u003dtbn:ANd9GcQktIi2AI4yZ308i8vaOlPBQgdMI6BmVtTl3myrAUiQ3L6oilXW","tw":300}</div>
'    </div>
```

Comment: I'm receiving this error " object variable or with block variable not set "

Comment: why would you not say which line is causing the error?

Comment: Sir I'm not able to identify it.

Comment: UPDATE: Sir it has worked out fine but it's giving me an error once it comes to a value that can't be found on Google. 
can you please modify the code to continue even after facing values that can't be found?

Comment: why can you not identify the line where the failure occurs?  how do you know that an error occurred, and what do you do when it occurs?

Comment: Sir it has worked really fine thank you. but as clarified when it comes to a value that can't be found on google it stops. I need you to modify the code to continue generating the links even while facing such values.

Comment: you have to attempt to write that code. when you get a value that cannot be found on google, the program probably "throws" an error. you have to check for that error, and then do process if there is no error   `get data from google .... if found then .... process data ....  end if`